# ¿Como finalizar activity usando el contexto?

Tags: java, android

estoy desarrollando un juego, pero estoy trabado en como finalizar un activity, ya que no funciona el método `finish()`.

Desde esta clase quiero poder finalizar un activity, desde la cual llamo a esta clase, el cual paso por el contexto(context).

`public class Ventana_Pausa {`

```
public Ventana_Pausa(final Context context) {
    final Dialog dialogo=new Dialog(context);
    dialogo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialogo.setCancelable(false);
    dialogo.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogo.setContentView(R.layout.pausa);

    ImageButton cerrar=dialogo.findViewById(R.id.IMB_Cerrar);
    ImageButton aceptar=dialogo.findViewById(R.id.IMB_Aceptar);

    aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,Menu.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);//aqui puedo ir a otra activity
            //pero aqui nose como finalizar un activity


        }
    });

    cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialogo.dismiss();
            Jugando.cron.pause();
        }
    });

    dialogo.show();
}
```

}

Fragmento de codigo de la clase del activity que quiero finalizar

```
pausa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (AudioManager.reproducir){
                    click.start();
                }

                cron.pause();

                new Ventana_Pausa(contexto);//aqui paso el contexto a la esa clase


            }
        });
```

Comment: ¿Te ha servido la respuesta que te he dejado?

Comment: ¿Tratas de finalizar una Activity  desde otra activity? @JorgeOvejero

Comment: Me sirvió la respuesta de @Gastón Saillén. Justo eso necesitaba

Comment: @JorgeOvejero respondió primero Sebastian Paduano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con lo siguiente deberia funcionarte de finalizar una Actividad desde otro contexto

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Me sirvió.

Comment: Ningún problema Jorge, lo que necesites solo pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con un cast al contexto:

```
((Activity) ctx).finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

**El método [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) pertenece a la clase [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)**

Por lo tanto si envías el contexto, no podrás llamar  [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) de esta manera:

```
public myMetodo(final Context context) {
 ...
 ...
   context.finish();
 ...
 ...
}
```

debes realizar una "casting" (conversión de tipos) a `Activity` para poder llamarlo sin problema :

```
public myMetodo(final Context context) {
 ...
 ...
   ((Activity) context).finish();
 ...
 ...
}
```